# Use default value if item not found in array

Tags: ruby, select

So I've got my code trying to select an object from an array of objects, and if the object isn't found, I want to create my defaults.

```
lead_time = lead_times.select{|d| LeadTimeProfile.new unless d.day_of_week == day }
```

however, from what I can tell, this is not returning me the devault LeadTimeProfile.

is there a way of doing this? Or have I got it right?

Comment: Not sure why this was flagged as 'not a real question', as I got a real answer, and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So I've got my code trying to select an object from an array of objects, and if the object isn't found, I want to create my defaults.

Take a look at [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)

```
lead_time = lead_times.find{ |d| d.day_of_week == day } || LeadTimeProfile.new
```

Answer (score 0):

filter your array first, and then do the construction

lead_time = lead_times.select{|d| d.day_of_week == day}.map {|d| LeadTimeProfile.new(d)}

Answer (score 0):

Passing a lambda as a parameter also works.

```
lead_time = lead_times.find(lambda { LeadTimeProfile.new } ){ |d| d.day_of_week == day }
```

Comment: Note that this is less efficient than the accepted answer, as it creates a lambda every time you run this, where the accepted answer simply does the `find` and potentially instantiates a LeadTimeProfile object with no extra lambdas to garbage collect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to get the same results as what Kyle posted. There is no difference between this and using a or gate other than maybe making chaining method calls a bit cleaner.

```
day = 2
lead_times.find(-> { LeadTimeProfile.new }) { |p| 
  p.day_of_week == day 
}.day_of_week
```